# Force Spring Boot @Scheduled method to be called "out of schedule" in case of failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduler

I have a Spring Boot (2.6.6) `@Scheduled` method, which fetches data from an external service every 10 minutes.

Under normal condition, I am happy with the interval. However I'd like to shorten it on a one-time basis if the data fetch fails (the service is temporarily not available) and force the method to be scheduled earlier.

Something like this:

```java
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
public void fetchData() {
    try {
        this.data = myServiceConnector.fetchData();
    }
    catch (MyServiceNotAvailableException ex) {
        // temporarily set the scheduling delay so it will happen again in 5 seconds - HOWTO?
    }
}
```

N.B. If it is relevant for the problem, the act of data fetching is a reactive code, so in fact it looks like

```java
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
public void fetchData() {
    myServiceConnector.fetchData()
        .doOnSuccess(fetchedData -> this.data = fetchedData)
        .doOnError(throwable -> 
            // temporarily set the scheduling delay so it will happen again in 5 seconds - HOWTO?
        )
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to make a single retry 5 seconds later, or you want to keep retrying every 5 seconds until success?

Comment: @Chaosfire I want is to retry it until success and then return to the static schedule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come with the following solution.

1. At the beginning, I manually schedule the `fetchData()` task to run immediately.
2. In the subscription time of the `fetchData()` `Mono`, based on the result of the fetch operation, I manually schedule the next run. As this happens at the end of the operation, it is an end-to-start interval and I don't have to solve potential problems of overlapped method runs.

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DataUpdaterService {

    @Autowired
    private MyServiceConnector myServiceConnector;

    private TaskScheduler scheduler;
    private final Clock clock = Clock.systemUTC();

    @Getter
    private volatile Data data = null;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        final ScheduledExecutorService localExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler = new ConcurrentTaskScheduler(localExecutor);
        // Schedule the task to run for the first time right now:
        scheduleFetchTask(Duration.ZERO);
    }

    private void scheduleFetchTask(Duration interval) {
        scheduler.schedule(this::fetchData, clock.instant().plus(interval));
    }

    private void fetchData() {
        myServiceConnector.fetchData()
            .doOnSuccess(fetchedData -> {
                this.data = fetchedData;
                // Schedule the task in the normal mode:
                scheduleFetchTask(Duration.ofMinutes(10));
            })
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                log.error("Error fetching data from myService", throwable);
                // Schedule the task in the retry mode:
                scheduleFetchTask(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .subscribe();
    }
}
```

The signature of the `myServiceConnector.fetchData()` is

```java
Mono<Data> fetchData()
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: Updated to show use of always [AlwaysRetryPolicy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/policy/AlwaysRetryPolicy.html) (retry until successful).

Seems like what you really need is just retry logic integrated into your `@Scheduled` method. Spring Retry is a Spring AOP project that could help you here. You can configure things like a number of retries, and a delay to wait before retrying. Broadly it would look like this (there is additional configuration necessary to enable this):

```
@Bean
public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
   RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
   AlwaysRetryPolicy policy = new AlwaysRetryPolicy();

   retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);


   return retryTemplate;
}
...

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
public void fetchData() {
    retryTemplate.execute(context -> {
        this.data = myServiceConnector.fetchData();
    });
}
```

The project has more information on [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry) is a guide from Baeldung.

Comment: Using RetryTemplate, you can set a RetryPolicy. AlwaysRetryPolicy describes what you are going for, but you can also build your own custom RetryPolicy if necessary.

Comment: Now it looks more promising, I will consider this, if I will not find a way to bend the scheduling :) Here I can see the challenge in putting it together with the reactive code.

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave another option here for completeness sake, but [OP's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71757821/17795888) looks the cleanest for his reactive case. Spring's [Trigger](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/Trigger.html) is used to calculate the next execution time. In this case it has to know if the task was successful or not. I did not find any way to notify the trigger through the API, my best idea was to use instance variable.

```
public class DynamicTrigger implements Trigger {

  private boolean isTaskSuccessFul = true;

  @Override
  public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
    Date last = triggerContext.lastCompletionTime();
    Instant lastCompleted = last != null ? last.toInstant() : Instant.now();
    int seconds = this.isTaskSuccessFul ? 10 : 3;
    return Date.from(lastCompleted.plusSeconds(seconds));
  }

  public void setTaskSuccessFul(boolean taskSuccessFul) {
    this.isTaskSuccessFul = taskSuccessFul;
  }
}
```

The task, with extremely simple simulation of every second task failing:

```
public class ThrowingRunnable implements Runnable {

  private int count = 1;

  @Override
  public void run() {
    int current = this.count;
    if (this.count++ % 2 == 0) {
      System.out.println("Task failed - " + LocalDateTime.now() + " - " + current);
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    System.out.println("Task success - " + LocalDateTime.now() + " - " + current);
  }
}
```

Another runnable, to wrap the task itself, handle the exception and notify trigger about success or failure:

```
public class WrappingRunnable implements Runnable {

  private final Runnable wrappedRunnable;
  private final DynamicTrigger trigger;

  public WrappingRunnable(Runnable wrappedRunnable, DynamicTrigger trigger) {
    this.wrappedRunnable = wrappedRunnable;
    this.trigger = trigger;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      this.wrappedRunnable.run();
      this.trigger.setTaskSuccessFul(true);
    } catch (RuntimeException exc) {
      this.trigger.setTaskSuccessFul(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Another possibility is to notify the trigger for failure through the error handler, but that would require transferring it with a custom exception and casting, i don't think it's worth it.

And scheduling the trigger manually:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
    ConcurrentTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ConcurrentTaskScheduler(Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor());
    taskScheduler.setErrorHandler(Throwable::printStackTrace);
    taskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);

    DynamicTrigger trigger = new DynamicTrigger();
    WrappingRunnable runnable = new WrappingRunnable(new ThrowingRunnable(), trigger);
    taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(runnable, trigger);
  }
}
```

**Edit:** Wrapping reactive code into `Runnable` can be like this:

```
public class MonoRunnable implements Runnable {

  private final MyService myService;
  private final DynamicTrigger trigger;

  public MonoRunnable(MyService myService, DynamicTrigger trigger) {
    this.myService = myService;
    this.trigger = trigger;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    this.myService.fetchData().doOnSuccess(data -> {
      //do stuff with data
      this.trigger.setTaskSuccessFul(true);
    }).doOnError(throwable -> {
      //do stuff with error
      this.trigger.setTaskSuccessFul(false);
    }).subscribe();
  }
}
```

I skipped `subscribeOn()`, cause i am not sure of the effects the `Worker` will have, considering the task will be scheduled with spring scheduler. On success and on error functions will take care of notifying the `Trigger`, and `WrappingRunnable` won't be needed, and we can directly register the mono task:

```
MonoRunnable runnable = new MonoRunnable(this.myService, trigger);
taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(runnable, trigger);
```

Comment: Yes, I also thought that something with the `Trigger` might work like this. I was just lazy to think about how to wrap the reactive code into it (or viceversa? how to wrap it into the reactive code? :) ). BTW, *when* and *by who* exactly is called `DynamicTrrigger.nextExecutionTime()` - what triggers this method? :) Is it the end of the `WrappingRunnable,run()`?

Comment: @HonzaZidek We have to wrap the reactive code into runnable to register with the scheduler, i'm not sure the other way around is possible. Logically speaking `nextExecutionTime()` should be called after `run()`, but i am not sure if it's waiting for `run()` to finish execution.